# VBA operator "Like" not correctly comparing 2 strings

Tags: string, excel, vba, compare

I've got a sub that is trying to compare 1 string (captured in givenVal) to a variety of possible acceptable strings (columns E through N of mapping sheet) which include things like wildcards and specific operators (like * ? # [] etc) so I feel most comfortable continuing using the "like" operator.

My problem is, even with a potential acceptable find, as shown in the screenshot, the flag is not being set correctly. Many of the fields are left as anything acceptable (so just *) and the blanks arent being accepted as falling under *, if that makes sense. I have tried debugging and the screenshot shows me tracking the 3 key parameters in the watch area.

Any ideas? Screenshot here...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM1zm.jpg

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Note, in your Dim lines every item needs a As clause, otherwise they are declared as Variant

Comment: To expand upon what Chris wrote, the `Like` operater returns `result` for `string Like pattern`.  In your code, you have `pattern Like string`.(See Help for the `Like` operator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dataValArray` contains the patterns, and `givenVal` contains the string to test, swap the parameters ie

```
givenVal Like dataValArray(j)
```